# Intro proofs problem3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the quotient of an integer and a nonzero rational number is a rational number.

Wondering if i did this correct

$m \in \mathbb{Z} $

$\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} $

By the definition of nonzero rational,   $ n = \frac {a}{b} $ for some $ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $b \neq 0$.

Consider : 
$ \frac {m}{n} = \frac {mb}{a}$. Let $x = mb, x \in \mathbb{Z} $

so:

$ \frac mn = \frac xa$

Therefore, by definition of rational numbers, the quotient of an integer and a nonzero rational number is a rational number.

Comment: More or less correct. Notice that $a\neq 0$ since $n$ is a non-zero rational number. Also, you could explain why $\frac{x}{\frac{y}{z}}=\frac{xz}{y}$ in general.

Comment: In my opinion, at the start it should be something like $m \in \mathbb{Z},$ and then $r=a/b \in \mathbb{Q},$ that is the letters used for expressing the integer and the fraction should not overlap.

Comment: @coffeemath yes, and that would then free up $n$ to be used where $x$ is now.

Comment: @Joffan With my setup, $mb$ would be $a,$ which it seems OP has called $x$ for some reason, But $mb$ wouldn't be $n$ --- Maybe so, but since the notation seems so unusual I didn't really try to follow the lines of OP's steps in his post.

Answer (score 1):

> $m \in \mathbb{Z} $
>
> $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} $

- that second definition doesn't really make sense, if what you are trying to do is specify $n$. Better to introduce your rational variable separately:

$ r\in \mathbb{Q} $

> By the definition of nonzero rational,   $ n = \frac {a}{b} $ for some $ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $b \neq 0$

- this neglects the "non=zero" part of the definition:

By the definition of rational,   $ r = \frac {a}{b} $ for some $ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $b \neq 0$, and since $r$ is non-zero, we also have $a\ne 0$

> Consider :
> $ \frac {m}{n} = \frac {mb}{a}$

Probably better to break this down a little more, and (at least briefly) use the operator version of division:

$ \frac mr = m \div r = m\div \frac ab = m \times \frac ba = \frac{mb}a$

($\frac ba$ is well-defined since we know that $a\ne 0$)

> let $x = mb, x \in \mathbb{Z} $

$ x \in \mathbb{Z} $ should be an inference:

let $x = mb$; then since $m,b  \in \mathbb{Z}$ we also have $x \in \mathbb{Z} $

> so:
>
> $ \frac mn = \frac xa$

- Could add

$x,a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a \ne 0 \implies \frac xa \in \mathbb{Q}$

> Therefore, by definition of rational numbers, the quotient of an integer and a nonzero rational number is a rational number.

$\square$